# what is a data only mode card

Tags: cisco, router, voip, video

I have a router (cisco 1841 modular router) and in the router's guide.  They guide says that the c1841 is a data-only mode, even the VWIC cards is data only.

I want to add a Polycom group series 500 to my network and apply the QOS on the router and the switches.   Will the c1841 support traffic for my video conference system?

Comment: tell us pls the model of your router, looks like, that this definition is vendor specific

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you're talking about Cisco tech... there's the WIC - data only, VIC - voice only, and VWIC - voice and data cards. Each depends on the router as to what functions are supported/supportable based on the IOS software and the slot in which the card is loaded.

For example, a 1750 (or 1751) has 2 WIC and 1 VIC slots. The VIC slot is keyed so a WIC won't seat in it -- and if you force it in there anyway, *it won't work*. A VIC will physically fit in a WIC slot, but will not function there. A VWIC can go in either slot, and will function based on the type of slot -- data only in a WIC slot, voice only in a VIC slot.

A 1760 has 2 VIC/WIC slots and 2 VIC slots. A VWIC in the first two slots can be configured for either voice or data operation.

Answer (score 1):

Well, QoS can work on L2/L3/L4 information, and as soon as your voice equipment - be it Polycom - packs the voice data into payload of IP packets, 1841 can apply QoS features on them.

The "voice" support on Cisco routers generally means ability to terminate voice input, or ability to output voice in digital or analog form. If that function is already embedded into voice terminal you're using, all 1841 will deal with is IP traffic.